# How to hand over a dataframe between tkinter buttons?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tkinter, callback

I'm pretty new with python programming and this is my first question asked, so be gentle with me. Right now i am working on a tkinter GUI that reads CSV files, turns them into dataframes to edit them and save the processed file to a result.csv in a datapath. My Problem is that i want to read in the CSV with a function OpenFile() connected to one button and then use the returned dataframe in my "Editfunctions" that each also is connected to a button. That doesnt seem to work with my callback in the code. Here is what my tkinter GUI currently Looks like:

```
root = tk.Tk()
openbutton = tk.Button (root, text='OpenFile', command = lambda: OpenFile())
openbutton.pack()
brakebutton = tk.Button (root, text = 'EditFile', command = lambda: EditFile(z))
brakebutton.pack()
savenewbutton = tk.Button(root, text = 'SavetoNewFile', command = lambda: SaveinNewFile(out_tup_end3))
savenewbutton.pack()
saveexcbutton = tk.Button(root, text = 'AppendtoExistingFile', command = lambda: SavetoexistingFile(out_tup_end3))
saveexcbutton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

MY functions essentially look like this:

```
def OpenFile():
      name = askopenfilename()
      df = pd.read_csv(name, sep = ';')
      return df

def EditFile(z):


        df1 = z[[]]
.
.
.
.
return out_tup_end3

def SaveinNewFile(out_tup_end3):
    out_tup_end3.to_csv("datapath", sep = ';', index = 0, mode = 'w')


def SavetoexistingFile(out_tup_end3):           
    with open("datapath", 'a') as f:
        out_tup_end3.to_csv(f, header=False, sep = ';', index = 0)


def main():   

    z = OpenFile()
    EditFile(z)
    editedFile = EditFile(z)
    SaveinNewFile(editedFile)
    SavetoexistingFile(editedFile)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

So I think the not properly working part is that the callback is not handing over the dataFrame read from OpenFile() to EditFile(z). How can i achieve that?
Thanks for the help in advance!!

Comment: I don't really understand what this program is supposed to be doing, but I do have a thought; Is it because z is out of scope?

Comment: I left out a little bit of code in the EditFile(z) Function where i Play around with the dataframe handed over from OpenFile(). But this handing over doesn't seem to work. Essentially i want to get rid of the Error that says: exception in Tkinter Callback.....NameError: name 'z' is not defined.

Comment: It seams in `command=lambda: EditFile(z)` you try to use `z` which exists only in `main()`. You have to create global variable `z` (outside all function) and use `global z` inside function. BTW: `command=` execute functions but it doesn't care of returned value - so `return df` is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`command=` executes function but it doesn't care of value returned from this function so you have to use `global` variables to use result from one function in other function.

You code could look like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo, showwarning
import pandas as pd

# --- functions ---

def open_file():
    # inform function to use global variables
    global df

    name = askopenfilename()

    if name:
        df = pd.read_csv(name, sep=';')
        showinfo("INFO", "DataFrame created")

def edit_file():
    # inform function to use global variables
    global df, out_tup_end3

    if df is None:
        #print("Read file first")
        showwarning("WARNING", "Read file first")
    else:
        df1 = df[[]]

        # ...

        out_tup_end3 = df1
        showinfo("INFO", "DataFrame edited")


def save_in_new_file():
    # inform function to use global variables
    global out_tup_end3

    if out_tup_end3 is None:
        #print("Read file first")
        showwarning("WARNING", "Read file first")
    else:
        out_tup_end3.to_csv("datapath", sep=';', index=0, mode='w')
        showinfo("INFO", "DataFrame saved")


def save_to_existing_file():           
    # inform function to use global variables
    global out_tup_end3

    if out_tup_end3 is None:
        #print("Read file first")
        showwarning("WARNING", "Read file first")
    else:
        with open("datapath", 'a') as f:
            out_tup_end3.to_csv(f, header=False, sep=';', index=0)
        showinfo("INFO", "DataFrame appended")


# --- main ---

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # create global variables

    df = None
    out_tup_end3 = None

    # GUI

    root = tk.Tk()

    b = tk.Button(root, text='Open File', command=open_file)
    b.pack(fill='x')

    b = tk.Button(root, text='Edit File', command=edit_file)
    b.pack(fill='x')

    b = tk.Button(root, text='Save to New File', command=save_in_new_file)
    b.pack(fill='x')

    b = tk.Button(root, text='Append to Existing File', command=save_to_existing_file)
    b.pack(fill='x')

    root.mainloop()
```

Or learn how to use classes and `self.` instead of `global`

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps a lot and i will definitly have a look into working with classes. But this works just fine for now.